# Why use document.getElementById when I can directly refer to the DOM id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE/Chrome: are DOM tree elements global variables here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

I recently discovered that I can use in javascript any object from DOM with a direct reference to its id:

```js
<div id="layer">IM A LAYER</div>
<script>
   alert(layer.innerHTML);
</script>
```

If this is true, what advantage I'd get using the getElementById method?

Comment: `var layer = "OMG WTF"; alert(layer.innerHTML)`

Comment: "This is doubly bad in that now you have to avoid naming your elements after any member of either the document or the window object you (or any other library code in your project) might want to use." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here?lq=1

Comment: This problem is not specific to element id but has to with the global scope of variables. This is very easily coped with whne specifically scoping variables, which can be dealed with by scoping with function() {}();

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Accessing a DOM element directly will give you a error if the element does not exist. Wheras if you use `getElementById` it will return `NULL`.

You also can't access all elements directly if they, for example, have dashes in their name (`some-id`), because JS variables can't contain dashes. You could however access tthem with `window['some-id']`.

Answer (score 6):

for example, if in your page you have elsewhere another previous script with

```
<script>
var layer = false; // or any other assignment
</script>
```

`layer` will be a reference to `window.layer`, then `layer.innerHTML` will fail. With `document.getElementById` you will avoid this tricky errors

Comment: getElementById when an element with that id will get just as tricky an error condision (undefined) as direclty accessing. Just lik the OP I don't see a the trickyness here. Please proof me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This will work only for `id`'s containing letters allowed for variable names. For id's like `text-11`, or `item-key-21` it won't work.