# What is the point in document.getElementById when you can select the element without it?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

Hello this might be a stupid question but what is the point in the document.GetElementById function when you can just select the element like so:

```
<html><body>
<p id="sampletext">I am the sample</p>

<script>
sampletext.innerHTML="I have just been changed" //This changes the inner HTML
</script>
</body></html>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something really obvious. Thanks.

Comment: If this works for you, go for it.

Comment: Afaik, things like this remain for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: What if you want to select a button, and add an even listener?

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478102/why-use-document-getelementbyid-when-i-can-directly-refer-to-the-dom-id-in-javas

Comment: I didn't know of this, actually seems really useful. I just advise you to check it works on different browsers and to make sure you don't name other variables equally (which is the only reason I would see it not being widely accepted)

Comment: @FabioLopez don't do it.....

Comment: eag845 thanks for that it clarified it completely. I tried searching for a similar question to mine to see if there were any duplicates beforehand but I didn't succeed.