# Start svg polyline exactly at right border of span element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple html file containing an SVG polyline:

Here's my code:

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
polyline{
    fill:none;
    stroke:red;
    stroke-width:3
}
```

```html
 <p>A block element containing an <span>inline element</span></p>
        <svg height="200" width="500">
            <polyline points="0,0 20,0 40,25" />
      </svg>
```

I would like to start the polyline exactly at the midpoint of my `span`'s right border. How can I do that?

Comment: Quick attempt - https://jsfiddle.net/bgzr190u/

Comment: @MrT Nice attempt, but if you reduce the width of the browser window you will see that it messes up the polyline positioning.

Comment: Another one - https://jsfiddle.net/dmg0r87f/ this one has an issue with overflow though

Comment: What do you mean by overflow?

Comment: On smaller screens you can see a horizontal scroolbar which can be fixed by setting `overflow: hidden`, but not sure if that is desired outcome - https://jsfiddle.net/fwr3a1ut/

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic idea: you give the svg `position:absolute` and the same size as the html element overlapped. You calculate the bounding client rect of the span and the position of the point where the polyline shpuld begin. Ypu either translate the polyline or you rewrite the points attribute so that it begins where you want it

```js
let bcr = sp.getBoundingClientRect();
poly.setAttribute("transform",`translate(${bcr.x+bcr.width},${bcr.y+bcr.height/2})`)
```

```css
svg {
  outline: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>A block element containing an <span id="sp">inline element</span></p>
</div>
<svg height="200" width="500">
  <polyline id="poly" points="0,0 20,0 40,25" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This looks really good but is the use of javascript really necessary here?

Comment: Also you appear to be calling the id name directly in JS without using the more conventional `getElementById` method. What is that called? I have never seen it...

Comment: you can use getElementById or querySelector if you prefer. In this demo I'm using the id because there is less code and - in my opinion - clearer and easier to understand

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478102/why-use-document-getelementbyid-when-i-can-directly-refer-to-the-dom-id-in-javas It seems like calling the id by name is a convenience feature which is less robust than `getElementById`. Good to know.